# A context-based partition_copy

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm trying to implement a general filtering model for my class `AlignedRead`. The idea is, at the start of the program the user options determine which series of filters should be applied to each `AlignedRead`. The difficulty is some of the filters are 'context-based' i.e. they are conditional on previously seen elements. For example, one context-based filter could be if the read is a duplicate, which requires the last seen read (input must be sorted).

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> // std::all_of, std::partition_copy
#include <iterator>  // std::cbegin etc

template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
class ReadFilter
{
public:
    using ContextFreeFilter  = std::function<bool(const AlignedRead&)>;
    using ContextBasedFilter = std::function<bool(const AlignedRead&, BidirectionalIterator,
                                                  BidirectionalIterator)>;

    void register_filter(ContextFreeFilter a_filter);
    void register_filter(ContextBasedFilter a_filter);
    template <typename OutputIterator1, typename OutputIterator2>
    void filter_reads(BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last,
                      OutputIterator1 good_reads, OutputIterator2 bad_reads) const;

private:
    std::vector<ContextFreeFilter> context_free_filters_;
    std::vector<ContextBasedFilter> context_based_filters_;

    bool filter_read(const AlignedRead& the_read, BidirectionalIterator first,
                     BidirectionalIterator previous) const;
};

template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
void ReadFilter<BidirectionalIterator>::register_filter(ContextFreeFilter a_filter)
{
    context_free_filters_.emplace_back(std::move(a_filter));
}

template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
void ReadFilter<BidirectionalIterator>::register_filter(ContextBasedFilter a_filter)
{
    context_based_filters_.emplace_back(std::move(a_filter));
}

template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
template <typename OutputIterator1, typename OutputIterator2>
void ReadFilter<BidirectionalIterator>::filter_reads(BidirectionalIterator first,
                                                     BidirectionalIterator last,
                                                     OutputIterator1 good_reads,
                                                     OutputIterator2 bad_reads) const
{
    BidirectionalIterator previous {first};
    std::partition_copy(first, last, good_reads, bad_reads,
                        [this, first, &previous] (const AlignedRead& the_read) {
                            return filter_read(the_read, first, (previous != first) ? previous++ :
                                               previous);
                        });
}

template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
bool ReadFilter<BidirectionalIterator>::filter_read(const AlignedRead& the_read,
                                                    BidirectionalIterator first,
                                                    BidirectionalIterator previous) const
{
    return std::all_of(std::cbegin(context_free_filters_), std::cend(context_free_filters_),
                       [&the_read] (const auto& filter) {
                           return filter(the_read);
    }) && std::all_of(std::cbegin(context_based_filters_), std::cend(context_based_filters_),
                      [&the_read, first, previous] (const auto& filter) {
                          return filter(the_read, first, previous);
    });
}
```

This works fine. However, I would like to make two changes that I'm finding difficult:

1. Support moving as well as copying (not currently possible as moving invalidates previously seen reads).
2. Pass the context-based filters the range of filtered 'good reads'.

Note solving 2. automatically solves 1. The main difficulty I'm facing is that in most cases a `std::back_insert_iterator` is used for `OutputIterator1`, and it [doesn't seem to be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531841/c-cast-from-back-insert-iterator-to-iterator-within-functors) to convert this into its underlying container iterator.

The only solution I can think of is having the user also supply a normal iterator to the start of the 'good reads', but obviously this has its own problems. Is there some neat trick I can use to solve this problem?

**Edit**
I've just realised that even the idea of passing in an additional iterator would not work as it may become invalidated if the underlying container resizes.

I'd also consider a solution which just keeps track of the last seen 'good read'. So context-based filters become of the form `std::function<bool(const AlignedRead&, const AlignedRead&)>`.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by making a new back inserter iterator that gives access to the `begin` and `end` methods of the underlying container, and also a little bit of TMP.

Here is the new iterator:

```
template <typename Container>
class ContextBackInsertIterator :
public std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
{
protected:
    Container* container;

public:
    using container_type = Container;
    explicit ContextBackInsertIterator (Container& x) : container(std::addressof(x)) {}
    ContextBackInsertIterator<Container>& operator= (const typename Container::value_type& value)
    { container->push_back(value); return *this; }
    ContextBackInsertIterator<Container>& operator= (typename Container::value_type&& value)
    { container->push_back(std::move(value)); return *this; }
    ContextBackInsertIterator<Container>& operator* ()
    { return *this; }
    ContextBackInsertIterator<Container>& operator++ ()
    { return *this; }
    ContextBackInsertIterator<Container> operator++ (int)
    { return *this; }

    typename container_type::const_iterator begin() const { return container->begin(); }
    typename container_type::const_iterator end() const { return container->end(); }
    typename container_type::const_iterator cbegin() const { return container->cbegin(); }
    typename container_type::const_iterator cend() const { return container->cend(); }
};

template <class Container>
inline
ContextBackInsertIterator<Container> ContextBackInserter(Container& x)
{
    return ContextBackInsertIterator<Container>(x);
}
```

Now the trick is to notice that for inserter-iterators, the `++` operator does nothing. The idea is that every time we see a 'good read' we use `++` on a copy of the given input iterator. If we are given a `ContextBackInsertIterator` we can call the `begin` and `end` methods of the iterator to get the last inserted element, if we are given a normal iterator we just parrot back the iterators. I statically determine if the given iterator is a `ContextBackInsertIterator` by checking if the `value_type` of the iterator is `void` - as it is for inserter-iterators - but I admit there is probably a better way.

```
template <typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename T::value_type>::value,
    typename T::container_type::const_iterator>::type
get_first(T first, T last)
{
    return last.begin();
}

template <typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<typename T::value_type>::value, T>::type
get_first(T first, T last)
{
    return first;
}

template <typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<typename T::value_type>::value,
    typename T::container_type::const_iterator>::type
get_last(T first, T last)
{
    return (last.begin() != last.end()) ? std::prev(last.end()) : last.begin();
}

template <typename T>
inline
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_void<typename T::value_type>::value, T>::type
get_last(T first, T last)
{
    return (first != last) ? std::prev(last) : last;
}
```

Finally, the `filter_reads` function changes as follows:

```
template <typename BidirectionalIterator>
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator1, typename OutputIterator2>
std::pair<OutputIterator1, OutputIterator2>
ReadFilter<BidirectionalIterator>::filter_reads(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                                                 OutputIterator1 good_reads,
                                                 OutputIterator2 bad_reads) const
{
    auto good_reads_last = good_reads;
    return std::partition_copy(first, last, good_reads, bad_reads,
        [this, good_reads, &good_reads_last] (const AlignedRead& the_read) {
        if (filter_read(the_read, get_first(good_reads, good_reads_last),
                        get_last(good_reads, good_reads_last))) {
            ++good_reads_last;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

I'm happy to accept another solution if anyone can improve on this.